# need to implement my algorithm using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made small algorithm and want to implement it using javascript. Here is my algorithm

I have a data in `data.json` file in this format

```
[
"109 200",
"109 201",
"102 202",
"103 202"
]
```

What I am trying to do is

1. Create four array containers i.e. c1, c2, c3 and c4.
2. Put above data in c1 container as it is
3. loop through c1 and put the data in c4 in following format

   ```
   "109",
   "200",
   "109",
   "201",
   "102",
   "202",
   "103",
   "202"
   ```
4. loop through c1 and put them in c2 in this format

   ```
   "109,200"
   ```
5. then check if c3 is empty then read first value from c2 and push it in c3.
6. repeat step 4 but this time put second data i.e. "109 201" from c1 in c2 in this format

   ```
   "109,201"
   ```
7. then check if c3 is not empty then loop through c2 and check if any of these two values are repeated in c4. If it is repeated then repeat step 6 and 7 until it finds least amount of numbers from data.json.

This algorithm is not efficient but still I want to use this.

Here is my code.

```
var teams = [],
    c1 = [], arr = [], left = [], right = [], j = 0,
    show = function () {
        var span = $('#list');

        $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (ids) {

            //c1.push(c);
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var a = smallcontainer(ids);
                var b = bigcontainer(ids);
                var c;

                if (c1 == "") {
                    c = a[0].split(" ");
                    console.log(c);
                } else {

                }


                //console.log(c);
                var id = ids[i];
                teams = id;
                $('<li>' + id + '</li>').appendTo(span);
            }
        });
    },

    smallcontainer = function (teams) { //arr
        arr = [teams[j]];
        j++;
        return arr;
    },

    bigcontainer = function (ids) { //c3. in code it is left+right=result
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var splitted = ids[i].split(" ");
            left.push(splitted[0]);
            right.push(splitted[1]);

        }
        var result = left.concat(right);
    };
```

**Update**

data inside data.json file has four teams with two members in each team in this form

```
"109 200" = Team 1
"109 201" = Team 2
"102 202" = Team 3
"103 202" = Team 4
```

So now I have to compute the smallest number of people and it has to select one member from each team from this list and show their IDs. So the output for above would be

```
109
202
```

**Latest update**

I am still waiting for help

**Solution**

Here is the solution with the help of AlexBEll and PAEz. I used solution below which was basically solved by AlexBell

```
var data = [
 "1009 2000", 
 "1009 2001", 
 "1002 2002", 
 "1003 2002", 
 "1004 2003", 
 "1005 2004", 
 "1006 2005", 
 "1007 2006", 
 "1007 2007", 
 "1008 2008", 
 "1009 2008", 
 "1010 2009", 
 "1011 2010", 
 "1012 2010"      
];

var first = [], second = [], result = {}, out = '';

//Separe the ids
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var el = data[i].split(' '); 
    first[i] = el[0];
    second[i] = el[1];
}

for(var k = 0; k < first.length; k++){

    //Count the elements
    var nOfFirst = countElemnts(first, first[k]);
    var nOfSecond = countElemnts(second, second[k]);

    //If the first is in more that second take it
    if(nOfFirst > nOfSecond){
        result[first[k]] = 0;
    //Else take the second        
    }else if(nOfFirst < nOfSecond){
        result[second[k]] = 0;
    //If is only one take it    
    }else{
        result[first[k]] = 0;
    }

}

function countElemnts(arr, el){
    var count = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[j] == el)
            count++;
    }
    //console.log(el+' : '+count);
    return count;
}

for(var n in result){
    out += 'The id n: '+n+' is in the list\n';
}

alert(out);
```

Comment: No offense, but what is the point? The way I see it, in the end you're just replacing a space with a comma?

Comment: @Jeff good point. I am completely confused how to implement this so I will appreciate help.

Comment: Please post what the end result should be - that way we can compare the start result with the end result, and create a propper algorithm with the least amount of code.

Comment: ok I am updating my post

Comment: "smallest number of people from this list" - how did you get to that result then? I am clearly misunderstanding ;)

Comment: Ok. There are three persons in Team 1 and 2 i.e. 109 is in both teams so selected this id would fullfil the requirement to select at least one id from each team. Second id is the same. 202 is in Team 3 and 4 and selected him would fullfil the same requirement.

Comment: So, you are returning the ID's of 2 members who are in the most teams?

Comment: I think this is still unclear. Can I provide you with link?

Comment: I am basically trying to achieve this using javascript or jquery. http://www.spotify.com/uk/jobs/tech/bilateral-projects/

Comment: This is way out of my league, I'm sorry :)

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15407/discussion-between-jeff-and-al0ne-evenings)

Comment: @Jeff I am on the chat. Are you there?

Comment: Could you check [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TRCyL/) if is correct? Just to know if I've understood the problem.

Comment: @AlexBall could tell me what is that n?

Comment: It does not work when I change input. Lets say if I add more teams to this it will still look for these very same value and ignore the rest of it.

Comment: @al0neevenings in the alert? is the number of occurence. I've tried with more data, and seem to work, ah probably there are some error ...

Comment: @AlexBall Lets say if I add this data `"109 200",
"109 201",
"102 202",
"103 202",
"104 203",
"104 204"` then it still pops up the same output i.e. `First: 109 repeated n: 2, Second: 202 repeated n: 2` and it ignores `104`.

Comment: @AlexBall you could also check this link. This is what I want http://www.spotify.com/uk/jobs/tech/bilateral-projects/

Comment: Ah ok: is because `if(qt1 > max1[1]){` is `>` and not `>=`, because 104 is repeated same time than 109. You want the last 104, or both 104 and 109? I've not correctly understood the question. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. I want to read one 104 since it is repeated. secondly, If you visit that link which I provided then you will understand what am I really want to achieve. please visit that link. thanks

Comment: @AlexBall now when I change `>` to `>=` as you mentioned above it returns this result `First: 104 repeated n: 2, Second: 202 repeated n: 2` which is incorrect again

Comment: Sorry but I was at work, however [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/TRCyL/1/) could go?

Comment: Thanks @AlexBall Seems working. How about after this comment `//If my friend is in the first column this the loop, else loop like dt[el[1]] = el[0] to be sure that he/she is in the result` there is not loop below this comment.

Comment: @al0neevenings I quickly read the text in the link, and demands that his friend is in the result. If your friend is in the first column fits this, otherwise you just change the code as suggested. If all goes well the place for an answer and continue the discussion there, otherwise it is better to continue in chat. Hope to be useful ;-)

Comment: Here what when I give this input `"1009 2000",
    "1009 2001",
    "1002 2002",
    "1003 2002",
    "1004 2003",
    "1005 2004",
    "1006 2005",
    "1007 2006",
    "1007 2007",
    "1008 2008",
    "1009 2008",
    "1010 2009",
    "1011 2010",
    "1012 2010"` then it outputs incorrect result.

Comment: Will you add this an answer so when it completely works then I ll accept and also can we start chat now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15416/discussion-between-al0ne-evenings-and-alex-ball)

Comment: @AlexBall Thanks for solution. It is working with more data as well. :-)

Comment: @al0neevenings ok good, I've found more solution, but I'm happy that work ;-)

Comment: You can post your solution to this post as answer so I will accept your answer and also if you have found more solutions and implemented that then also post them here for future visitors ofcourse. :-)

Comment: @AlexBall read my above comment.

Comment: hehe...not to nit pick or anything, but... Mine is faster on longer lists  (on tiny lists Alex's is a tiny weeny bit faster, on longer lists Im alot faster) http://jsperf.com/puzzle , Alex's doesnt have the mate check and it will fail on this data set `"1009 2000","1009 2001","1002 2002","1002 2003","1005 2004","1005 2005","3003 1009","3003 1002","3003 1005"`

Comment: Alex's will also fail on this data set `"1009 2000","1009 2001","1002 2002","1002 2003","1005 2004","1005 2005","1006 2006","1006 2007","1009 3003","1002 3003","1005 3003","1006 3003"` 3003 should not be in the winners list

Comment: DAM! mine fails aswell if the data set is `     "1009 3003",
     "1002 3003",
     "1005 3003",
     "1006 3003",
     "1009 2000", 
     "1009 2001", 
     "1002 2002", 
     "1002 2003",
     "1005 2004",
     "1005 2005",
     "1006 2006",
     "1006 2007",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?....

```
var teams=[
"109 200",
"109 201",
"102 202",
"103 202"
];

var members ={};

var matesId='109';

// Members that won
var wins={};

// First lets find out how many teams a member is in
for (var i=0,length=teams.length; i<length;i++){
  var temp = teams[i].split(' ');
  for (var z=0,zlength=temp.length;z<zlength;z++){
    if (!members[temp[z]]) members[temp[z]]={wins:0,totalTeams:0,id:temp[z]};
      members[temp[z]].totalTeams=members[temp[z]].totalTeams+1;
  }
    teams[i]=[members[temp[0]],members[temp[1]]];
}

for (var i=0,length=teams.length; i<length;i++){
  var member1=teams[i][0];
  var member2=teams[i][1];
  if (member1.totalTeams>member2.totalTeams){
    member1.wins=member1.wins+1;
  } else if (member1.totalTeams<member2.totalTeams){
    member2.wins=member2.wins+1;
  } else {
    member1.wins=member1.wins+1;
    member2.wins=member2.wins+1;
  }    
}

for (var i=0,length=teams.length; i<length;i++){
  var member1=teams[i][0];
  var member2=teams[i][1];
  if (member1.wins>member2.wins){
    if (wins[member2.id]!==true) wins[member1.id]=true;
  } else if (member1.wins<member2.wins){
    if (wins[member1.id]!==true) wins[member2.id]=true;
  } else if (!wins[member1.id] && !wins[member2.id]) {
    if (member1.id==matesId && member2.id==matesId) {
      wins[matesId]=true;
    } else{
     // A draw, so pick one
      Math.round(Math.random())==1 ? wins[member2.id]=true : wins[member1.id]=true;
    }
  }    
}

var keys=Object.keys(wins);
var results=[];
results.push(keys.length);
for (var i=0,length=keys.length; i<length;i++){
  results.push(keys[i]);
}
results=results.join('\n');
document.querySelector('#output').innerText=results;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PAEz/dLUqj/3/
EDIT: Updated it so its a little easier to read.
EDIT: Realised you dont need a draw and win, just a win will do.
LAST EDIT: Noticed one small error, it should all be right now.

Comment: What are you running it in?  When I run it in Chrome the output shows `2 109 202`

Comment: I got 3 warnings, just got rid of 2 but dont know how to get rid of the one on line 49..but it works.  I wonder what your 4th warning is?  Do you get any errors in chrome console?

Comment: no I am not getting errors in console. But it doesnt work at all for me.

Comment: Yep.  http://jsfiddle.net/PAEz/dLUqj/  I was originally going to do it on JSFiddle, but thought Id give Bin a try.  Works for me on the fiddle aswell.